# How to get the float value from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd, mplfinance as mpf, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

db = yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=7), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m")
db = db.dropna()
```

If i wanted to get the float value i would just do this "

```
db.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp('2022-02-16 12:05:00'))
```

and it would produce `34`
So :

```
b =db[33:34]
```

But if i do this:

```
db.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(b.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [Index(['2022-02-22 09:15:00'], dtype='object', name='Datetime')] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> to Timestamp
```

Could you please advise how can i get the index from datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `b.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')` return one element Index, so for scalar need select first value:

```
b = db.iloc[33:34]
print (b)
                             Adj Close  Volume  
Datetime                                        
2022-02-16 12:15:00-05:00  2709.629883    8000  

print (b.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'))
Index(['2022-02-16 12:15:00'], dtype='object', name='Datetime')

print (b.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')[0])
2022-02-16 12:15:00
```

---

```
a = db.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(b.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')[0]))
print (a)
33
```